# Magento 2 - Plugins on some classes don't work in etc/frontend/di.xml

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, plugin, dependency-injection

I'm trying to do this:

```
<type name="Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList">
    <plugin name="a_name_plugin" type="Mynamespace\Mymodule\Plugin\Model\Payment\MethodList\Plugin" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

It isn't activated if I place this declaration in `etc/frontend/di.xml`.
But it works in `etc/di.xml`.
I want it to be active only on frontend.

Why it would not work from `etc/frontend/di.xml` or how to make it work ?

Using Magento 2.0.7
Magento mode is developer.
Cache should not be a problem. var/generation/* was cleaned a few times.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

most probably you are not actually in the `frontend` area: try putting it into `etc/webapi_rest/di.xml`